# Async tasks and Sqlite

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite

I have a service that runs when device is connected to the internet. It fetches data from sqlite which is then uploaded on the server. A listfragment has been populated with the data from the database.

Since I have service, I am getting errors like "database already closed" "database not opened". 
My dbHelper object is static.
I am calling `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` at the start of each method that will acess the database. And db.close() at the end of each method.

Should I close the `db.close()` only in `onDestroy()`? ... Would this solve the issue or is there another way?

Comment: Show your `dbHelper` code. DO you open it once during application lifetime?

Comment: yes i open it once in oncreate of mainactivity.

Comment: Can i have different database handlers for the same database?.. i guess that will solve my prob.

Comment: Yes you can try to have different handlers for each case. Otherwise you should close your single `db` in `onDestroy` in main activity.

Comment: i tried closing the db in OnDestroy(). But then the service that runs in background does not have access to it when it needs. I guess the best solution would be to have a separate DB Helper for activity and service respectively.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if you ever want to close a database, you have to check if it is `isOpen()`.

Now, in general your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation sould be a singleton and override the `close()` method to be:

```
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    mOpenConnections--;
    if (mOpenConnections == 0) {
        super.close();
    }

}
```

where `mOpenConnections` is a member that holds the number of connections made through the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. this member should be incremented everytime somebody opens the database.

```
@Override
public synchronized void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    // increment the number of users of the database connection.
    mOpenConnections++;
}
```

then when you need to close a database use `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()` method.

This should solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I have found to work reliably across multiple activities is to call getWritableDatabase in the onCreate method of every activity.

As has been pointed out, any service should have its own SQLiteOpenHelper instance. I think this happens anyway, because the service runs in a separate address space, but it is best to make sure.

Comment: i tried using a separate SQLiteOpenHelper for the service. But If i close my app immediately after the service is triggered, i get "Database not open" error. Isn't a service supposed to run independent of the activity?

Comment: You are probably better off not closing the database explicitly. It gets closed anyway when the helper gets deleted.

Comment: the helper would be deleted if the Main Activity is destroyed. But they service will continue to run in the background. So i made a separate helper for the service, it works the way i wanted. :)

Comment: do not make a separate ```SQLiteOpenHelper``` for the service. the service is part of the application and runs on the same process (and even on the same main thread, if you did not explicitly created a new thread). and generally it is a **very** bad idea to have multiple instances of the SQLiteOpenHelper handling the same database.